# Exception with Google Datastore in firestore mode

Tags: arrays, datastore

When executing a GQL query in Datastore which includes a "IN ARRAY(..)", the query execution does not always complete correctly: it is seems it depends on the specific fetch entities.
More precisely, the exception is fired by the java version of the DS API, when executing the hasNext method on the QueryResults object, i.e. when reading al returned entities.
For example, it can get back the first entity and then fire an exception on the second invocation of hasNext. It is a repeatable behavior, always with the same entities.

Example of query execution:

```
String sql = "SELECT *  FROM myentity WHERE myfield IN ARRAY('abc','efg') and some other conditions LIMIT 10001 OFFSET 0";
GqlQuery.Builder builder = GqlQuery.newGqlQueryBuilder(sql);
builder.setAllowLiteral(true);
GqlQuery query = builder.build();
QueryResults response = datastore.run(query);
while(response.hasNext()) { // <- here there is the error
        entity = (Entity)response.next();
...
}
```

The exception fired is:

Can't get the number of an unknown enum value.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get the number of an unknown enum value.
at com.google.datastore.v1.PropertyFilter$Operator.getNumber(PropertyFilter.java:233)
at com.google.datastore.v1.PropertyFilter$Builder.setOp(PropertyFilter.java:929)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery$PropertyFilter.toPb(StructuredQuery.java:519)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery$CompositeFilter.toPb(StructuredQuery.java:237)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery.toPb(StructuredQuery.java:1011)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery.populatePb(StructuredQuery.java:975)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:71)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.computeNext(QueryResultsImpl.java:93)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)

It happens also with the google java API version of datastore of dicember 2022, so it seems not related to a specific version.

I don't want any exception!